# Installing Nvidia drivers on rhel 8.6 with dkms but getting asm/kmap_types.h and drm/drmP.h errors in build

Tags: rhel, nvidia, display, dkms

I'm trying to install the nvidia drivers for my T1000 Quadro on my Rhel 8.6 Lenovo p15.  However I'm running into errors when trying to build and install the driver.

System info?

```
root:Downloads# hostnamectl | grep Kernel
            Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64
root:Downloads# lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU117GLM [Quadro T1000 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ad000000-adffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ae080000-ae0fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=3840x2160 resolution=3840,2160 visual=truecolor xres=3840 yres=2160
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:163 memory:6040000000-6040ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
root:Downloads# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
```

I got my driver from nvidia, [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/148435/en-us).

```
root:Downloads# ls -l | grep NVIDIA
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 brad brad 110600229 May 29 22:22 NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26.run
```

When I run the run script I get the following for the DKMS step:

```
  ERROR: Failed to run `/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 430.26 -k 4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64`:
         Building module:       
         cleaning build area...                                                                         
         'make' -j12 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64
         IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH='' modules....(bad exit status: 2)                                          
         Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64 (x86_64)
         Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.26/build/make.log for more information.
```

What does the make log say?  [This (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/NefstKqy) and sample below.

```
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64/scripts/Makefile.build:315: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.26/build/nvidia/nv-mmap.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64/scripts/Makefile.build:315: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.26/build/nvidia/nv-i2c.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64/scripts/Makefile.build:315: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.26/build/nvidia/nv-mempool.o] Error 1
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.26/build/nvidia/nv-p2p.c:15:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.26/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:118:10: fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/kmap_types.h>         /* page table entry lookup          */
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64/scripts/Makefile.build:315: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.26/build/nvidia/nv-p2p.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64/Makefile:1577: _module_/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.26/build] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:157: sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64'
make: *** [Makefile:81: modules] Error 2
```

What if you don't try to install it with dkms?  Well I want to, but ok...

```
  ERROR: An error occurred while performing the step: "Building kernel modules". See
         /var/log/nvidia-installer.log for details.
```

and

```
  ERROR: An error occurred while performing the step: "Checking to see whether the nvidia kernel module
         was successfully built". See /var/log/nvidia-installer.log for details.
```

and of course

```
  ERROR: The nvidia kernel module was not created.
```

...

```
  ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.     
         You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux  
         driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Well what does that log say?  Alright, the [nvidia-installer (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/k0ENjng0) and sample.

```
   make[3]: *** [/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64/scripts/Makefile.build:316: /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia/nv-instance.o] Error 1
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia/nv-procfs.o
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia/nv-acpi.c:15:
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:118:10: fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory
    #include <asm/kmap_types.h>         /* page table entry lookup          */
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[3]: *** [/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64/scripts/Makefile.build:316: /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_fault_buffer_flush_test.o] Error 1
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-modeset.o
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-fb.c:29:
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-fb.h:30:10: fatal error: drm/drmP.h: No such file or directory
    #include <drm/drmP.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[3]: *** [/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64/scripts/Makefile.build:316: /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_peer_identity_mappings_test.o] Error 1
   make[3]: *** [/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64/scripts/Makefile.build:316: /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-helper.o] Error 1
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.o
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.c:27:
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.h:33:30: error: field 'base' has incomplete type
        struct nv_drm_gem_object base;
                                 ^~~~
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.h:37:5: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool dumb_buffer;
        ^~~~
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.h: In function 'to_nv_nvkms_memory':
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.h:46:19: error: 'NULL' undeclared (first use in this function)
        if (nv_gem != NULL) {
                      ^~~~
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.h:46:19: note: 'NULL' is defined in header '<stddef.h>'; did you forget to '#include <stddef.h>'?
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.h:31:1:
   +#include <stddef.h>
    
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.h:46:19:
        if (nv_gem != NULL) {
                      ^~~~
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.h:46:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.h:47:16: error: implicit declaration of function 'container_of' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
            return container_of(nv_gem, struct nv_drm_gem_nvkms_memory, base);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.h:47:37: error: expected expression before 'struct'
            return container_of(nv_gem, struct nv_drm_gem_nvkms_memory, base);
                                        ^~~~~~
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.h: In function 'to_nv_nvkms_memory_const':
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.h:56:19: error: 'NULL' undeclared (first use in this function)
        if (nv_gem != NULL) {
                      ^~~~
   /tmp/selfgz30846/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.h:56:19: note: 'NULL' is defined in header '<stddef.h>'; did you forget to '#include <stddef.h>'?
```

Finally, what if any status does your nvidia driver have?

```
root:Downloads# nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

How about dkms?

```
root:Downloads# dkms status
nvidia/430.26: added
```

So I'm not too sure of what is wrong here but it looks like I have some missing modules a `kmap_types.h` and a `drmP.h`.  What are these?  Where can I find them for RHEL 8.6?  How can I install them?  Also I assume once the driver builds and installs correctly, I should no longer have an `UNCLAIMED` display?  Tanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

it is because that functionality was intentionally removed from the kernel-devel package in Redhat 8.6

Issue
Module build fails on RHEL8.6 as kmap_types.h is removed from kernel-devel.